# Custom InputFormat or InputReader for Excel files(xls)

Tags: java, excel, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to read a excel(xls) file stored on Hadoop cluster. Now I did some research and found out that I need to create a **custom InputFormat** for that. I read many articles but none of them is helpful from programming point of view. If someone can help me with sample code for writing custom inputformat so that I can understand the basics of "Programming InputFormat" and can use Apache POI library to read the excel file.
I had made a mapreduce program for reading text file. Now I need help regarding the fact that even if I some how manage to code my own **custom InputFormat** where would I write the code in respect to the mapreduce program I have already written.

PS:- converting the .xls file into .csv file is not an option.

Comment: Please share if you have any solutions for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should create `RecordReader` to read each record from your excel document. Inside that record reader you should use POI like api to read from excel docs. More precisely please do the following steps:

1. Extend `FileInputFromat` and create your own `CustomInputFrmat` and overrride `getRecordReader` .
2. Create a `CustomRecordReader` by extending `RecordReader` ,here you have to write how to generate a key value pair from a given filesplit. 
   So first read bytes from filesplit and from that bufferedbytes  read out desired key and value using POI.

You can check myown CustomInputFormat and RecordReader to deal with custom data objects here
[myCustomInputFormat](https://github.com/thomachan/Custom-MR/tree/master/src/mapreduce/hi/api/input)

Comment: Can you please mention how to read the binary data and den convert them to string for getting the values in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Your research is correct. You need a custom InputFormat for Hadoop. If you are lucky, somebody already created one for your use case.

If not, I would suggest to look for a Java library that is able to read excel files.
Since Excel is a proprietary file format, it is unlikely that you will find an implementation that works perfectly.

Once you found a library that is able to read Excel files, integrate it with the InputFormat.

Therefore, You have to extend the [FileInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) of Hadoop. The `getRecordReader` that is being returned by your ExcelInputFormat must return the rows from your excel file. You probably also have to overwrite the `getSplits()` method to tell the framework not to split the file at all.

Comment: There is a library called apache POI that can read an excel file. But the problem for me is integrating it with InputFormat. Any help in that regard??

Comment: Hi, sorry, I did not see this Apache POI library. I extended my answer a little bit.